# Typescript how do I dynamically use type of object property

Tags: typescript

Say I have some code like this:

```js
type Action = {
    type: string;
    data: /* need help here */;
};

// data is a string here
const action1: Action = {
    type: 'foo',
    data: 'bar'
};

// data is an object here
const action2: Action = {
    type: 'complex',
    data: {
        first: 'John',
        last: 'Doe'
    }
};

// data is not defined here
const action3: Action = {
    type: 'undef'
};

// and so on, the point is data can be anything
```

I want to have the type of `data` be whatever the type of `data` is on the object so that the previous code example will not give me any compiler errors. **I don't want to use `any`** because I want to have my editor's intellisense help with the type when I type. Is there a way in Typescript to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: So, you want something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpLZ6m)?

Comment: @caTS That's extremely close to what I want. I'm assuming the function used for initializing the objects is necessary?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you will have to use `const act: Action<...> = { data: ... };`, essentially duping the type you want. The function is there to infer the type for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'd mark your comment as the answer if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generic like this to represent that the type of `data` be potentially anything:

```
type Action<T> = {
    type: string;
    data?: T;
};
```

But when you define a variable, you would essentially have to duplicate the type, which is not useful. So that's why we need a function to infer the generic for us:

```
function action<T = undefined>(a: Action<T>): Action<T> {
    return a;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpLZ6m)